# How to reach some commands on Github for windows

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I want to pass github for windows because of easy usage and its user friendly design.
But I have to know some codes which i used classical version of Github.

For example how to reach these commands?

"gitk -all"

"git reset --hard HEAD"

"git diff"

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

[Mark Cramer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/852795/mark-cramer) adds [in  the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120905/how-to-reach-some-commands-on-github-for-windows/15888066?noredirect=1#comment38816949_15888066) (July 2014):

> With GitHub for Windows 2.0 the drop-down menu has changed slightly.
>   Select the repository you wish to work with (on the left) and then from then "**`Open in Git Shell`**" from the drop-down and you'll get a window that will enable you to enter command line commands.

---

Original answer (April 2013):

Actually, you don't need to download a separate msysgit if you are using GitHub for Windows: it does come with its own msysgit installation within GitHub for Windows (a Portable_Git, [as I mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13290969/6309)).

You can simply launch a command prompt (Powershell) session, which will use that git.exe from the internal nested "PortableGit":

[image: Commad prompt for GitHub for Windows]

In there, you can type any git command you want.

Comment: With GitHub for Windows 2.0 the drop-down menu has changed slightly. Select the repository you wish to work with (on the left) and then from then "Open in Git Shell" from the drop-down and you'll get a window that'll enable you to enter command line commands

Comment: @MarkCramer Interesting. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Just download the http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads and install it, you will have all git commands in your command line.

Comment: Right. GitHub is not the same thing as Git.