# GitHub GUI for Windows: uses old version

Tags: windows, git, github

I have Windows 8.1 on my laptop and I've installed Git. If I type `git --version` in Windows' command prompt, the result is `git version 1.8.5.2.msysgit.0`. I can commit and update all the stuff on the server, everything works fine.

At the same time, I'd like to have a GUI for that so I've installed GitHub for Windows. Unfortunately, it does not let me commit my changes as it report that there is an error as suggests opening a shell (also console-like, but looks different from usual Windows' cmd). If I type in that shell `git --version` I get `git version 1.8.4.msysgit.0` so apparently the GUI app uses an older version of git than the one I need, although I have a needed version of Git installed on my computer.

I appreciate any hints on how to make the GUI app to use the new version of git. If any details are still needed, please tell me - I'll provide them asap. Thanks

Comment: GitHub for Windows uses its own embedded version of git.

Comment: @SLaks: thanks, that's what I suspected. Any advise how to substitute this with a newer version?

Answer (score 1):

You will find the git (embedded in [G4W -- GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) as [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21372275/github-gui-for-windows-uses-old-version/21376227#comment32229759_21372275)) in

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\GitHub\Portable_Git_xxxxx\
```

(See "[Can the credentials stored in Github for Windows be shared with the whole operating system?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13290969/6309)")

You can *try* and replace that folder by a [portable Git](https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=3&q=portable&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20ReleaseDate%20Size%20DownloadCount), `PortableGit-1.8.5.2-preview20131230.7z`: once uncompressed, you can rename the folder with the same name '`Portable_Git_xxxxx`' and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks, that helped upgrade the version (at least G4W's shell now report the same version 1.8.5.2), however still when I am cloning using G4W I get `fatal: ***.git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?`. When I do cloning using cmd, it all goes fine and there are no problems. Shall I ask a separate question?

Comment: @Ilya I suspect G4W reads the `%APPDATA\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_xxxx\VERSION` (which isn't part of a regular msysgit installation archive). Try to put a file named `VERSION` in that `Portable_Git_xxx` folder, with `753d3d695406affabf6310fc4a98d13acddb11ae` in it, and name your `Portable_Git`: `Portable_Git_753d3d695406affabf6310fc4a98d13acddb11ae`