# GitHub undo a discard

Tags: github, repository, undo

I was working on some files and accidentally discarded all the files from github. I know that as soon as you discard there is an undo button at the bottom. But I restarted my gitub and now I do not have the undo button anymore. Is there any way I can undo my discard and get back my files? I hope there is, pls let me know if you have any ideas.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The discard (that you can see in "[Undo Button in GitHub for Windows](https://github.com/blog/1441-undo-button-in-github-for-windows)") is available to reset files added to the index.

[image: https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/1396/278196/785c1940-90df-11e2-9c77-189a907c6580.gif]

That means you added files, and reset them *before* any commit.

The GitHub for Windows/Mac won't help you there.

You need to recover those files from the git repo (`git fsck --unreachable --no-reflogs --no-cache HEAD`).
See "[Recovering added file after doing `git reset --hard HEAD^`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15472831/6309)" for more.

The [OP Benz_java](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1975139/benz-java) mentions "[restoring lost commits](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/01/17/restoring-lost-commits.html)", for looking in the reflog for lost commit.

Comment: This post was very helpful too: http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/01/17/restoring-lost-commits.html

Comment: @Benz_java indeed, for restoring commits. I have included your link in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Thanks guys, this helped me to recover all of my week's work!

Comment: @VonC Thank you. Also, I have seen you before from a different answer a year or two ago. Good to see another helpful answer from you again :)

Comment: @Marvin No problem. I am here everyday (https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122976/6309).