# Undo discarded changes in SourceTree

Tags: git, svn, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using SourceTree and i had some modified files under "Working Copy Changes" section which were being tracked as shown by the yellow icon in the image. But i discarded those changes. Now how to revert those changes?[image]

Comment: By "revert", do you meaning "restore the changes that have just been discarded"? Were those changes added to the index at any point?

Comment: Yes i mean restore.And i have no idea whether they were added to index or not.

Comment: If they were added, you can try http://stackoverflow.com/a/22346161/6309

Answer (score 0):

If the items are not staged (in the top pane), you can revert them by right-clicking on one or multiple items and clicking "revert". This will perform `git checkout -- filename` for each selected item.

Comment: "Revert" has a different purpose.It is for reverting the changes made since last commit.