# Github failed to clone repository on windows 7 application

Tags: windows, git, github

When trying to clone a remote repository to my machine I get the error:

"failed to clone the repository 'somerepo'"
"The process timed out. The repository is in an unknown state and likely corrupted. Trying deleting it and cloning it again"

This same error happened to someone else with the same environment and fixed it by just cloning it again. That didn't work for me. The repo is not the issue here.

Comment: How are you sure that the repo is not the issue. I'm not saying it isn't, but what leads you to this proclamation?

Comment: One reason is that another person and I started the clone at the same time and theirs was successful and mine was not. On top of that many others have cloned it successfully in the past.

Comment: What version of Git are you using? Are you using MinGW 32 git for windows?

Comment: I assume the latest version of GIT because in the instructional guide in github where you have to install GIT, it says "Skip the guide. Download our native app instead.". I have a 64 bit machine.

Comment: `git --version` will tell you what version you are using. There no other way to be sure what version you are using. `1.8.3.msysgit.0` is the latest one for windows. You will need the msysgit version of git, i.e. Git for windows. Otherwise nothing is going to work correctly on your machine.

Comment: Okay the version I have is 1.76.msysgit.0 (checked using git bash), so I guess the first step in trying to solve this problem is updating my version of Git.

Comment: That would be the place to start. I'm not really sure how to do that though without just re-installing Git, but the internet might know. Good luck

Comment: I've updated GIT. The same issue occurs when trying to clone the repo.

Answer (score -1):

First, if you are cloning with [GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/), then the [latest msysgit is included in it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11928949/6309): you just need to [open a shell from G4W](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15888066/6309).

Second, if the issue persists (from an independent up-to-date msysgit, or from G4W), then it should be some connection issue (network, firewall, blocked port...)