# GitHub for Windows: How to commit only a part of the file?

Tags: git-commit, github-for-windows

I am new in GitHub for Windows. I learn how to commit a single change.
But i don't understand how can i commit only a part of file.
On GitHub for Mac you can just select the line.

How can i do it on GitHub for Windows?

Comment: Did you look in the help pages?

Comment: Ok, is not supported yet.
This is what they reply from the support:

Hi Francesco,

Currently we don't support line-by-line staging, but this is something we'd like to add in the future to GitHub for Windows. Thanks for letting us know you'd like to see it.

Cheers,
Steve

Comment: git add? then commit?

Comment: Hey man, if you read the title, there is written: How to commit ONLY A PART of the file

Comment: Update January 2015: GitHub for Windows has just implemented just that! See my [edited answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18531719/6309).

Comment: Discussion to improve the discoverability of staging line-by-line in GitHub Desktop:   https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/1688

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Update: January 2015, 14th: [**Partial commits in GitHub for Windows**](https://github.com/blog/1940-partial-commits-in-github-for-windows):

> The newest release of [GitHub for Windows](https://windows.github.com/) supports selecting lines or blocks of changes when creating a commit. Simply click the desired lines in the gutter, create the commit, and leave the other changes for you to continue working on.

[image: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/359239/5745722/ab3d336e-9bdf-11e4-8001-fc7316e8155b.gif]

The GitHub post adds what I mentioned in my original answer below:

> For people familiar with the command line, this change is similar to interactive staging using `git add -i` or `git add -p`.

---

(Original answer: Aug. 2013)

From GitHub for Windows, you can **[open the console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15888066/6309)**, and type:

```
git add -p -- path/to/your/File
```

You will then be able to stage exactly what you want from that file.

[`git add --patch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add):

> Interactively choose hunks of patch between the index and the work tree and add them to the index.
>   This gives the user a chance to review the difference before adding modified contents to the index.

Comment: Are the lines you choose those which will be committed or the other way around?

Answer (score 3):

I know I am a bit late on this thread. But I was facing an issue where the selected code block was not getting added when I click on the line I wanted to include in the commit. Just make sure you've disabled the **Hide whitespace changes** checkbox in the settings menu.

[image]